# loading script-file has no effect and gives an error

Tags: javascript

I'am loading a script file like the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

         (function(){
                  var s=document.createElement("script");
                  var e=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                  s.async=1;
                  s.src="http://www.huntinggrounds.de/test.js";
                  e.parentNode.insertBefore(s, null);
         })();

         test.hello();       

   </script>
```

Here I'am calling the function test.hello() witch is defined in the script-file.

But I will get an error: TypeError: test.hello is not a function

What I'am doing wrong?

Here is also my test.js:

```
var test = test || {};
test.hello = (function(){
  console.log("say hello function");
});
```

PS: The script is still there and shown in console.

I'am trying to do something like google do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');         //http://www.google-analytics.com/u/ga_debug.js


        ga('create', 'UA-9098414-2', 'auto');
        ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: What if test.js is not loaded by the time test.hello() is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not waiting for your script to finish downloading. Instead, add an event listener, and execute your function as soon as it has loaded.

```
s.addEventListener('load', function() {
    test.hello();
});
```

Comment: how has google realized this. There is no eventlistener.

Comment: There are tons of other possibilities. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the Google APIs...

Comment: google doesn't call anything from the script inside the code you have shown, it's all declared in that jumbled block... if you want it to wait, you have to add the script via document.write()